# Understanding how different nested elements with "fixed" and "absolute" positions behaviour

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

It's a simple code, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer yet

As far as I understand, all absolute-positioned HTML elements get their position based on the nearest non-static/positioned ancestor (so any fixed or relative ancestors would influence on the absolute positioned element's position). Correct If I'm wrong, please

The element with "fixed" position gets its position based on the viewport, ALWAYS.
Said that, I give you this code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

div > div {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
}

#children {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="parent"></div>
  <div id="children"></div>
</div>
```

Result to this:

[image: Result]

Why when manually setting the #children element position with "top: 0px" isn't moving down 1px relative to the #parent element? Since absolute-positioned elements get their position based on fixed elements?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got what you mean, but `#parent` and `#children` are siblings, not ancestor and descendant.

Comment: I'm going to close this as a typo, because you've apparently confused yourself by setting IDs of elements to `parent` and `children` without actually making them parents or children, respectively. If you actually make them parent and child, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/bg61ryw2/